# Create a more compact script

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question regarding the folowing javascript code:

```
var item1 = nr[1]; var item1_nosp = item1.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
var item2 = nr[2]; var item2_nosp = item2.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
var item3 = nr[3]; var item3_nosp = item3.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
var item4 0 nr[4] ....... and so on
```

Is there a way to simplify this code?

I need both the variables: `item1` and `item1_nosp`.

Comment: i'm new to javascript. could you give me an short example please.

Comment: You do **not** need `item1` since it's `nr[1]` exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a for loop

```
var items_nosp=[];
for(i=1;i<nr.length;i++){
    var item1 = nr[i];
    items_nosp.push(item1.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: @RonnyHabets If this answer helped you, please click the check mark next to the answer to close your question and award points to the user who solved your problem.